# "java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host" between two Docker Containers

Tags: docker, containers, ibm-cloud

Note: Question is related to Bluemix docker support.

I am trying to connect two different Docker Containers deployed in Bluemix. I am getting the exception:

```
 java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host
```

when I try such connection (Java EE app running on Liberty trying to access MySQL). I tried using both private and public IPs of MySQL Docker Container.

The point is that I am able to access MySQL Docker Container from outside Bluemix. So the IP, port, and MySQL itself are ok.

It seems something related to the internal networking of Docker Container support within Bluemix. If I try to access from inside Bluemix it fails, if I do from outside it works. Any help?

UPDATE: I continued investigating as you can see in comments, and it seems a timing issue. I mean, it seems once containers are up and running, there is some connectivity work still undone. If I am able to wait around 1 minute, before trying the connection it works.

Comment: Are they running on one host or on different hosts?

Comment: I can't answer. Both containers are deployed within Bluemix and the platform decides what and where. Me, as an end user, don't have access to such info. I just know they both have a private and public IPs.

Comment: So you're saying that container 1 can't talk to container 2 on either the public or private ip?

Comment: Right. I had one deployment that worked fine. Is it possible that if containers are deployed in different hosts as Chasmo asked before, there is any kind of firewall or anything? Still investigating...

Comment: I had it failing. Then I restarted the frontend container (not redeployed) and then it worked. Don't understand. I didn't touch anything of the source code, neither of the backend container. Still investigating...

Comment: Ok. I suspect perhaps my app executes before everything is setup. If I deploy the frontend container, when appsrv starts, my startup EJB try the connection and fails. After two or three minutes I execute the same logic and it works. If I restart the container it works also. But if I redeploy the container it fails again when starting.

Comment: Ok. I added an sleep of 30 seconds to my code, and then it connects well always. So it seems the code of my container runs before some connectivity in the platform still being setup. Does it make sense for you? Still investigating...

Comment: I detected 30 seconds some times is not enough. 60 seconds has worked fine during all the day. Still investigating...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

60 seconds should be the rule of thumb for the networking start working after container creation.

Comment: Thanks @ywang. Do you know if such "rule" is documented anywhere?

Comment: The [document](https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/containers/container_single_ov.html#container_single_cli) says there is approximately 30s wait, but sometimes it could take a bit longer, and we're working on making the wait shorter. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks a lot @ywang, I missed that paragraph.