# Container can't talk to another container

Tags: ibm-cloud

App container instance (172.31.0.41) can't connect to DB container instance (172.31.0.38). See the following log detail:

> ... [INFO] cat.gencat.graelles.config.DatabaseConfiguration - Database URL: jdbc:mysql://172.31.0.38:3306/graelles ... Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server. ... Caused by: java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339) at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200) at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182) at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579) at com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:213) at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.(MysqlIO.java:297) ... 156 more

Perhaps there may be a network issue related to my account... or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

according to 
https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/containers/container_single_ov.html#container_single_cli

a starting container will be able to use its network connections approximately 30 seconds after booting is complete, even if the reality suggests that (in this moment) you can be sure to have a working network interface after max 60 seconds.
Could you check that the error you are getting is happening only during the container's first seconds and after 60 seconds it works fine?

Answer (score 0):

I have been suffering similar issue these past days and here are my findings: ["java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host" between two Docker Containers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32796008/java-net-noroutetohostexception-no-route-to-host-between-two-docker-container) don't know if they can help you.